# How to move a marker in Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, move, google-maps-markers

I'm using the Google Maps API V3 and I'm trying to make a marker move across the screen. Here's what I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<style type="text/css">
  html { height: 100% }
  body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
  #map_canvas { height: 100% }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function initialize() {
  var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(50,50);
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatLng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

  image = 'bus.gif';
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: myLatLng, map: map, icon: image});

  marker.setMap(map);
}

function moveBus()
{
  // Move Bus
}

</script>
</head>

<body onload="initialize()">
<script type="text/javascript">
moveBus();
</script>
<div id="map_canvas" style="height: 500px; width: 500px;"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Now what I've tried is replacing // Move Bus with

```
marker.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(0,0));
```

But that didn't do anything. That's the command I saw on the API reference. I'm also relatively new to Javascript, so it might be a JS error on my part.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

`moveBus()` is getting called before `initialize()`. Try putting that line at the end of your `initialize()` function. Also Lat/Lon 0,0 is off the map (it's coordinates, not pixels), so you can't see it when it moves. Try 54,54. If you want the center of the map to  move to the new location, use `panTo()`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/Rsp22/

HTML:

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#map-canvas 
{ 
height: 400px; 
width: 500px;
}
```

Script:

```
function initialize() {

    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng( 50, 50 ),
        myOptions = {
            zoom: 4,
            center: myLatLng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            },
        map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById( 'map-canvas' ), myOptions ),
        marker = new google.maps.Marker( {position: myLatLng, map: map} );

    marker.setMap( map );
    moveBus( map, marker );

}

function moveBus( map, marker ) {

    marker.setPosition( new google.maps.LatLng( 0, 0 ) );
    map.panTo( new google.maps.LatLng( 0, 0 ) );

};

initialize();
```

Comment: This might be a dumb question, but why is moveBus() called before initialize() in my code? Doesn't the onload script happen before anything in the body?

Comment: Your moveBus() call is not in an onload block, just a script block in the body. It gets parsed as soon as it's read. You could do something like: window.onload = function(){ moveBus(); };

Comment: Can you help me with how i can do this without adding a new map but move the marker to an existing one?

Comment: This does not work or not efficient. See solution below for draggable: true

Answer (score 14):

Just try to create the marker and set the draggable property to `true`.
The code will be something as follows:

```
Marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latlon,
    map: map,            
    draggable: true,
    title: "Drag me!"
});
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: This works like a charm. but how to get that dragged position ?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the correct API, but is the "marker" variable visible to the entire script. I don't see this marker variable declared globally.

Comment: According to http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_variables.asp assigning a value to undeclared variables makes them global.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
    #frame{
        position: fixed;
        top: 5%;
        background-color: #fff;
        border-radius: 5px;
        box-shadow: 0 0 6px #B2B2B2;
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 8px 8px;
        width: 98%;
        height: 92%;
        display: none;
        z-index: 1000;
    }
    #map{
        position: fixed;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 99%;
        height: 93%;
        display: none;
        z-index: 1000;
    }

    #loading{
        position: fixed;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        opacity: 1!important;
        margin-top: -100px;
        margin-left: -150px;
        background-color: #fff;
        border-radius: 5px;
        box-shadow: 0 0 6px #B2B2B2;
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 8px 8px;
        max-width: 66%;
        display: none;
        color: #000;

    }
    #mytitle{
        color: #FFF;
        background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,#d67631,#d67631);
        //  border-color: rgba(47, 164, 35, 1);
        width: 100%;
        cursor: move;
    }
    #closex{ 
        display: block;
        float:right;
        position:relative;
        top:-10px;
        right: -10px;
        height: 20px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .pointer{
        cursor: pointer !important;
    }

</style> 
<div id="loading">
    <i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin fa-2x"></i>
    Loading...
</div>
<div id="frame">
    <div id="headerx"></div>
    <div id="map" >    
    </div>
</div>


<?php
$url = Yii::app()->baseUrl . '/reports/reports/transponderdetails';
?>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>

<script>
    function clode() {
        $('#frame').hide();
        $('#frame').html();
    }
    function track(id) {
        $('#loading').show();
        $('#loading').parent().css("opacity", '0.7');


        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '<?php echo $url; ?>',
            data: {'id': id},
            success: function(data) {
                $('#frame').show();
                $('#headerx').html(data);
                $('#loading').parents().css("opacity", '1');
                $('#loading').hide();
                var thelat = parseFloat($('#lat').text());
                var long = parseFloat($('#long').text());
                $('#map').show();
                var lat = thelat;
                var lng = long;
                var orlat=thelat;
                var orlong=long;
                //Intialize the Path Array
                var path = new google.maps.MVCArray();
                var service = new google.maps.DirectionsService();


                var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng), myOptions = {zoom: 4, center: myLatLng, mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP};
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), myOptions);
                var poly = new google.maps.Polyline({map: map, strokeColor: '#4986E7'});
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: myLatLng, map: map});

                function initialize() {
                    marker.setMap(map);
                    movepointer(map, marker);
                    var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager();
                    drawingManager.setMap(map);
                }

                function movepointer(map, marker) {
                    marker.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng));
                    map.panTo(new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng));

                    var src = myLatLng;//start point
                    var des = myLatLng;// should be the destination
                    path.push(src);
                    poly.setPath(path);
                    service.route({
                        origin: src,
                        destination: des,
                        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
                    }, function(result, status) {
                        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                            for (var i = 0, len = result.routes[0].overview_path.length; i < len; i++) {
                                path.push(result.routes[0].overview_path[i]);
                            }
                        }
                    });

                }
                ;

                // function()
                setInterval(function() {
                    lat = Math.random() + orlat;
                    lng = Math.random() + orlong;
                    console.log(lat + "-" + lng);
                    myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
                    movepointer(map, marker);

                }, 1000);



            },
            error: function() {
                $('#frame').html('Sorry, no details found');
            },
        });
        return false;
    }
    $(function() {
        $("#frame").draggable();
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the full code with no errors**

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
        <style type="text/css">
          html { height: 100% }
          body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
          #map_canvas { height: 100% }

          #map-canvas 
        { 
        height: 400px; 
        width: 500px;
        }
        </style>

   </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function initialize() {

            var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng( 17.3850, 78.4867 ),
                myOptions = {
                    zoom: 5,
                    center: myLatLng,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                    },
                map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById( 'map-canvas' ), myOptions ),
                marker = new google.maps.Marker( {icon: {
                    url: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png',
                    // This marker is 20 pixels wide by 32 pixels high.
                    size: new google.maps.Size(20, 32),
                    // The origin for this image is (0, 0).
                    origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                    // The anchor for this image is the base of the flagpole at (0, 32).
                    anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 32)
                }, position: myLatLng, map: map} );

            marker.setMap( map );
            moveBus( map, marker );

        }



        function moveBus( map, marker ) {
            setTimeout(() => {
                marker.setPosition( new google.maps.LatLng( 12.3850, 77.4867 ) );
                map.panTo( new google.maps.LatLng( 17.3850, 78.4867 ) );
            }, 1000)


        };



        </script>
        </head>

        <body onload="initialize()">
        <script type="text/javascript">
        //moveBus();
        </script>

        <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=AIzaSyB-W_sLy7VzaQNdckkY4V5r980wDR9ldP4"></script>
        <div id="map-canvas" style="height: 500px; width: 500px;"></div>



        </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score -4):

**use panTo(x,y).This will help u**