# save coordinates from Google Map in Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers, jsfiddle

Hello i have a simple question!I would like to have a marker with google maps which i will move it and the coordinates (lan,lon) will be saved in two varriables with Jsfiddle (Javascript). I found a code (with HTML and CSS) but itsn't what i need beacause it has two markers and its different...Thank you so much in advance!

https://jsfiddle.net/irinikonsta/ryvpo5ux/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>Street View side-by-side</title>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
  <div id="pano"></div>
  <div id="floating-panel">
    Origin:
    <input type="text" readonly id="origin"> Destination:
    <input type="text" readonly id="destination">
    <br> Heading:
    <input type="text" readonly id="heading"> degrees
  </div>
  <script>
    var marker1, marker2;
    var poly, geodesicPoly;

    function initMap() {
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 4,
        center: {
          lat: 37.983810,
          lng: 23.727539
        }
      });
      map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(
        document.getElementById('info'));
      marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        draggable: true,
        position: {
          lat: 38.017973,
          lng: 23.694077
        }
      });
      marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        draggable: true,
        position: {
          lat: 37.990920,
          lng: 23.751755
        }
      });
      var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
        marker1.getPosition(), marker2.getPosition());
      map.fitBounds(bounds);
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'position_changed', update);
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker2, 'position_changed', update);
      poly = new google.maps.Polyline({
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 3,
        map: map,
      });
      geodesicPoly = new google.maps.Polyline({
        strokeColor: '#CC0099',
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 3,
        geodesic: true,
        map: map
      });
      update();
    }

    function update() {
      var path = [marker1.getPosition(), marker2.getPosition()];
      poly.setPath(path);
      geodesicPoly.setPath(path);
      var heading = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(path[0],
        path[1]);
      document.getElementById('heading').value = heading;
      document.getElementById('origin').value = path[0].toString();
      document.getElementById('destination').value = path[1].toString();
    }

  </script>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/jskey=AIzaSyBojvE89boyOqT01eKQd-UV_Dc4dpLRpzw&libraries=geometry&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Your question is not entirely clear but it sounds like you want to save the position of where you drag the markers, so that when the page reloads they are automatically there? This could be possible with the `localStorage` JavaScript API to store information between sessions. Take a look at the documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: @BlakeSimpson that you said,  this is exactly what i want. Is there anything more specific that i can use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your questions is not so clear...... Buuuut...... What you need is something like this http://jsfiddle.net/yorch/z67mxhbu/1/ ?

Just keep `marker`, `lat` and `lng` as global variables and store them when necessary (in this case I've choosen `dragend` event, but you can [check all events here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events))

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', update);
```

and then in the update method do your magic, in my case:

```
function update() {
  var path = marker.getPosition();
  lat = path.lat();
  lng = path.lng()
  alert("Lat: " + lat + "\nLon: " + lng);
}
```

---

**NOTE:** jsfiddle based on example from http://thinkingstiff.com/ in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8024951/3850595)

Comment: thank you so much! That was exactly what i needed! You gave a very nice script in jsfiddle. Although, i would like to ask a simple question about this... how can i put those varriables (lat, lng) in this phrase afterwards (bacause i tried but it didnt work)? Thank you so muuuch!                                getBase64FromImageUrl("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?location=lat,lng&size=300x300&pitch=90")

Comment: @IriniK. in which phrase you mean?

Comment: In this phrase (if you open it you will see it, i's a url): @jordi castilla                                            getBase64FromImageUrl("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?location=lng,lat&size=300x300&pitch=90")

Comment: just replace lat and lng like this `var phrase = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?location=" + lat + "," + lng + "&size=300x300&pitch=90%22";`